# Failure while implementing a tree view from an API in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, treeview, material-design

I am trying to implement a Material Design Tree View, which completely loads the data from an API. However, my implementation is throwing out errors. The HttpClient import seems to be fine, I don't get what is wrong. I tried mendling with the code without any avail.

My .scss file:

```
.example-tree-progress-bar {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.example-tree-invisible {
  display: none;
}

.example-tree ul,
.example-tree li {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

My .html file:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <li class="mat-tree-node">
      <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      {{node.name}}
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.name}}
      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

My .ts file:

```
import {NestedTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTreeNestedDataSource} from '@angular/material/tree';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

/**
 * Food data with nested structure.
 * Each node has a name and an optional list of children.
 */
interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  children?: FoodNode[];
}

/* const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Banana'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        children: [
          {name: 'Broccoli'},
          {name: 'Brussels sprouts'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [
          {name: 'Pumpkins'},
          {name: 'Carrots'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
]; */



const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [];



/**
 * @title Tree with nested nodes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class TreeNestedOverviewExample {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FoodNode>(node => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<FoodNode>();

  constructor(private client: HttpClient) {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
    const API_URL = 'https://urlhere.com/gettreeview';
  this.client.get(API_URL, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
    (res) => { this.TREE_DATA.push(res);console.log('Res: ', res); },
  );
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
```

My errors:

```
core.js:5882 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
main.ts:12 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

My JSON, which is fetched from the API:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "- Admin",
      "children": [
         {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jimmy"
         },
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Tom"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "- Users",
      "children": [
         {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Scott"
         },
         {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "John"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "- Developer",
      "children": [
         {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Robert"
         },
         {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Scarlett"
         },
         {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Johnson"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are missing the `HttpClientModule` import in your module.

Add the following to app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

After that add in the import section like

```
 imports:[HttpClientModule,  ]
```

See working Angular 9 [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-httpclient-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

**Edit:**

For working mat-tree examples check [Angular Mat-Tree docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples)

- Mat Tree example: [Tree with dynamic data](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nkjlgjkdpam?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts)
- Mat Tree example: [Tree with flat nodes](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxmbxbdmdde?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts)

**Edit2:**

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzxumf) for your example, but you have to set your own url ;-)

Comment: Now I'm getting `core.js:5882 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: `this.TREE_DATA` seems to be `undefined` ;-) `TREE_DATA` is no class member in fact you can't use `this`

Comment: But I defined it with `const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [];`, didn't I?

Comment: Ok, I deleted this and now there's no error, the console.log outputs correct data, but no tree is displayed.

Comment: if you don't push any data, the tree is empty =)

Comment: But I do push res, which is the result.. And `res` is printed out with `console.log` and appears to be correct.

Comment: Please share a Stackblitz to show your code OR have a look and the mat tree docs: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxmbxbdmdde?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/nkjlgjkdpam?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts

Comment: I am getting another error in StackBlitz now... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbnel3 And I already checked out the documentation it does not seem to help me further...

Comment: Seems to be throwing the same error on StackBlitz, however on my PC I am getting new errors when I removed `this` from `this.httpOptions`:

Comment: `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:72:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FoodNode'.
      The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
        Property 'name' is missing in type 'Object' but required in type 'FoodNode'.
    
    72     (res) => { TREE_DATA.push(res);console.log('Res: ', res); },
                                     ~~~
    
      src/app/app.component.ts:11:3
        11   name: string;
             ~~~~
        'name' is declared here.`

Comment: You realized i updated the answer? Please Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzxumf There is not FoodNode

Comment: Yes I did. Your StackBlitz also appears to show a list rather than a tree/tree view.

Comment: Because the data has no children. Adapt the code with your custom data.

Comment: It works, but the chavron is not displayed to me correctly https://imgur.com/a/bxJlxYk